# Transformer ratio changes when varying voltage on primary

Tags: transformer, voltage-measurement

I want to measure mains voltage using a transformer. bought a 9V transformer, removed the secondary and rewind it with 10 turns that gives me 2mV per volt 1:500.

[image]

The problem is that the ratio is not constant, the ratio decreases from 1:530 to 1:470 as voltage increases on the primary (primary voltage range is 0-250VAC).

- Why is this change in ratio happening and how I can compensate for it?

**Update**: I tried winding 10 turn around the primary but problem still exists, I also decreased the load from 100Ω to 10KΩ.

**Update2**: When I wind another secondary around the primary, the first secondary was in place and I had two secondaries, I removed the first secondary and left with only one secondary winded around the primary.
Now the ratio is much more stable, ranging from 1:470 to 1:490.

[image]

Comment: What were you expecting from an xfmr with high leakage?

Comment: @RohatKılıç What's the alternative?

Comment: Increase the coupling between primary and secondary by winding the secondary "on top of" the primary, not next to it.

Comment: How do you vary the primary voltage?

Comment: @Bryan Using a Variac.

Comment: What was the rated input voltage on it?

Comment: @winny 220V, did I overdrive it with 250VAC?

Comment: Depends on construction. 50/50. Measure the input current. If it suddenly jumps up, you’re saturating it.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I did wind another 10 rounds around the primary but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: what happened when you increased the load to 10k from 100R?

Comment: If you keep your measuring leads where they are but let the tips touch the same side of your resistor, do you reliably measure 0V?  Measuring voltages in the presence of magnetic fields is inherently problematic...

Comment: `I did wind another 10 rounds` what do you mean "another"? Do you keep the winding shown in the pic and wound "another 10 turns" around the primary? Or did you remove it and re-wind around the primary? You must have one primary and one secondary, and the only secondary should be wound around the primary.

Comment: @danmcb There was not any noticeable difference.

Comment: @user107063 Yes, the DMM reads 0V.

Comment: @RohatKılıç First I had the secondary winding that I wound was in place and then I wind another secondary around the primary. after reading your comment I removed the first secondary and only one secondary around the primary remained. I tested it and it's a lot more stable. the ratio now only changes from 1:470 to 1:480. is there anyway to improve this?

Comment: @ElectronSurf another way to improve further is called "sandwich winding" but that requires the primary to be unwound first.

Comment: @RohatKılıç So basically if primary have 300 turns every 30 turn of primary I do 1 turn of secondary so I'll end up with 10 turn of secondary?

Comment: @ElectronSurf that'll be even better but it's not what I meant because it's practically too difficult and not worth. Wind 150 turns (half) of primary, don't cut the wire, wind all your secondaries around this half primary (spread into the window if you can) and then wind the remaining primary on top of the secondary. Each half of the primary is a "bun", and the secondary is the "beef burger". Google "sandwich transformer winding" for further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *primary voltage range is 0-250VAC*

So, with 250 V RMS on the primary, the secondary voltage will be 500 mV RMS but, depending how you measure the secondary voltage could give you a significant error due to the common-mode voltage due to capacitive coupling between primary and secondary. This doesn't produce an error voltage but, that common mode voltage could cause your measurement equipment to be a lot less accurate.

> *Why is this change in ratio happening and how I can compensate for it?*

There is no change in ratio; just an error in your measurement method. I suggest you ground one of the secondary wires, ground the laminate stack and repeat and, if this doesn't clarify the situation then please disclose your measurement method in detail.

---

It would have been very helpful to know if you got a linear relationship between input voltage and output voltage before you "adjusted" the secondary so radically. I mean, there was very little reason to rewind it because, using a resistive potential divider would have achieved the same result.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149026/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-transformer-ratio-changes-when-varying-voltage); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.